# How to refer to an instance from a different class in the current class in Java

Tags: java, class, object, collision

I am working on bounding box collision of a laser colliding with a monster in Java. There is no problem with collision. The problem is the Rectangle object inside the OneEye class is static!

Problem 1: This is no problem if one monster was in the game but in my game I will be adding a lot of instances of the Monster class. So my Rectangle object cannot be static if I were to add more than one monster.

Problem 2: Note: if Rectangle object is non-static my getter method for Rectangle needs be non-static.

But I cannot seem to figure how to fix these two problems.

Again, my collision works! It is more of a code design flaw if I were to add different instances of the same class. To sum it all up, how do I refer to an instance from a different class in the current class I am writing code without referring to it in a static context.

Here's my code of two classes: Laser class and OneEye Class

```
public class Laser {

/* use a bounding box 
     * to test collision detection
     * 
     */
    private Rectangle rect;

   public void update(long milliseconds) {

// surround a bounding box around the laser
        rect = new Rectangle((int)position.x,(int)position.y,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
        // collision against the OneEye monster
        if(rect.intersects(OneEye.getRectangle()))
        {
            Game.getInstance().remove(this);
        }


}

public class OneEye {

/*
     * use bounding box
     * for collision 
     * detection
     */
    private static Rectangle rect;

public void update(long milliseconds) {

        // surround a bounding box around the oneEye monster
        rect = new Rectangle((int)position.x,(int)position.y,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
}

// can be useful for collision detection
public static  Rectangle getRectangle()
    {
        return rect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to go the no-static route, without a doubt. Simply make the rect Rectangle variable and the `getRectangle()` method non static. If this causes further problems, then you will want to post the details of these problems.

**Edit** You state:

> I tried that. But then the problem comes up: I cannot call getRectangle method (which is in my Monster class) in my Laser class.

The problem is not that you can't call `getRectangle()` in the Laser class, but rather that you can't call it on OneEye,. something that you've told us little about. I was assuming that OneEye is a Monster *variable* not a Monster subclass. If the latter, then your design is off as you should be calling methods on class instances, not on the classes themselves.

**Edit 2**
OK, now that I see OneEye, I see that it is a class, not an instance. Don't try to call methods off of this. Instead either create a oneEye variable that holds a Monster object, or a OneEye class that extends Monster, but either way, don't call `getRectangle()` on a class. Call it on a variable that refers to a Monster or Monster child class object.

Comment: I tried that. But then the problem comes up: I cannot call getRectangle method (which is in my Monster class) in my Laser class.

Comment: Dang, The class was suppose to be OneEye not Monster. I edit the post. My apologies for confusing you. Disregard the class name Monster which was a mistake.

Comment: @Nicholas: yes, trust me, it is the only way. Otherwise you end up with a program full of nothing but statics, completely lacking in ability to inherit, to encapsulate, ... to use all the advantages of object-oriented programming.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23428/discussion-between-nicholas-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)